# How to recreate this SQL(ite) query with an inner select and groupby in the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So, I'm trying to run a query and I can't get it to work properly. I have managed to write a SQL query that does what I'm looking for, but I'm struggling to move it into the Django ORM.

As a sidenote: even though the SQL query does what I'm looking for, I'm not sure it's the best way of creating such a query anyway. So, for completeness sake I'll recreate a similar situation as I'm in, so please let me know if there's a better way to create such a SQL query (and in turn maybe an easier way to turn it into Django ORM code).

Imagine a very simple movie database:

```
class ReleaseType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # e.g. CD/DVD/BD

class Movie:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # e.g. Harry Potter

class MovieRelease:
    movie = models.ForeignKey(to='Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(to='ReleaseType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # e.g. Harry Potter: Special Edition
```

Now imagine I want to list all movies that have **both** a DVD and BD movierelease.

I've worked out the following SQL (note: I haven't tested this *exact* same sql because the above is just a  simplified fictive example, but it's the same just with other column names):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT m.id, mr.type_id FROM moviedb_movie m JOIN moviedb_movierelease mr ON m.id=mr.movie_id WHERE (mr.type_id=1 OR mr.type_id=2))
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) >= 2
```

(I'm using SQLite as database)

So, as I said above, I'm not able to transform the above SQL query into a Django ORM query. I'm especially running into problems with the sub-select query. I can't seem to be able to replicate that in Django, everything I try gets lumped into a single SELECT, which messes up the expected output. I know it's possible to run raw SQL, but ideally I'd like to avoid that.

Now, there is an extra requirement that the 'type-filter' (in this case the DVD and BD), must also be dynamic. So, there can be more than two. But, I expect that won't be incredibly difficult to implement with Q objects, once I have the actual query working.

Can anyone help me out or give me some pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Django ORM way to achieve the desired result as your SQL query would be as follows -

```
dvdOrBDMovies = Movie.objects.annotate(total=Count('id')).filter(Q(total__gte=2) & (Q(movierelease__type=1) | Q(movierelease__type=2)))
```

However, I would recommend that if your MovieReleases can have more than one ReleaseTypes, Then instead of the Foreign key use an m2m relationship. That will make it much easier to handle.

link for many to many relationships from Django Docs - [Django Many to Many Relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't think it's gonna work, at least not exactly as you typed it out. You're filtering type_id on the Movie object, but it's a property of the MovieRelease object. I tried out the query (though edited to my real situation of course) and changed that type_id to the type_id of the movie_release. And it did not return the desired result either. When looking at the generated SQL, it seems you're running into the same issue I was running: because it doesn't do a sub SELECT, it ends up returning all movies that have either a DVD or BD release, and not only both.

Comment: In your SQL query, You mentioned type_id = 1 OR type_id = 2. So I wrote the query that way. It can easily be changed to have both DVD and BD by changing the symbol between the Qs from | to &. for the Column, I made the mistake. Check my updated answer

Comment: Yes, in the SQL query there's an OR, because an AND is not going to work there. It's not possible for a single movierelease to have two types at once. I think you misunderstand the working of the query I wrote (though, to be fair, it might be a very crude query haha). The subselect selects all distinct movie/type combinations of movies that have a movierelease with either type 1 OR type 2. Then the outer select does a count on the movie-ids and because of the DISTINCT, it means that all movie-ids that appear twice, ar movies that have both types of releases (it becomes an AND).

Comment: I understood your point. But when run with the distinct, ORM is not able to figure out the queryset. That's why I removed distinct from the Query. I think you should go ahead with m2m. That is much easier and a better way to handle this.